# Using KCL/KVL to derive differential equation of a mixed RLC-ciruit

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks, kirchhoffs-laws

I have the following LTI sinusoidal circuit, and I am trying to derive its differential equation using KCL and/or KVL. I need this to derive the Power Factor as function of the components, so I can optimize it. Solving the equations is generally no problem.

I already asked a similar question a while ago, but what got me confused this time is that my teacher said that I should end up with two equations, one depending on C and the other depending on L, but that is not what I derived.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQGkjl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If I am correct:

$$i(t) = i_{C1} + i_{L1} + i_R$$
With $$i_R = i_{L2} = i_{C2}$$

$$v(t) = v_{C1} + v_{L1} + v_{R} + v_{L2} + v_{C2}$$

But if I use the i(t), and derive the differential equation, then I find the same equation of a simple parallel RLC-circuit. This does not seem correct, and I do not find the two equations my teacher was talking about.

I am allowed to use the identities:

$$v_b(t) = L_b \frac{d i_b (t)}{dt}, i_b (t) = C_b \frac{d v_b (t)}{dt}, v_b (t) = R_b i_b (t)$$
With $$i(t) = I_m \cos(\omega t + \phi_i), v(t) = V_m \cos(\omega t + \phi_v), \phi = \phi_u - \phi_i, etc.$$

I am a math student btw, so unfortunately my circuit-theory knowledge is limited.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you got wrong here is the Kirchhoff's laws : while you're right on the current laws, you made a little mistake on the voltages : they are equivalent in each parallel wire, so that :
$$
v(t) = v_{C1}(t) = v_{L1}(t) = v_R(t)+v_{C2}(t)+v_{L2}(t)
$$
Note that these equations are given without regard to the sign and the conventions.
This way should lead you to the proper solution.
Always remember : the Kirchhoff's laws says that the sum of all the voltages in a loop (closed network) is equal to zero, and that the sum of all currents in a node are equal to zero.

Comment: Ah yes you are right! So basically I will get two equations, one depending on C1 and the other on L1 if I solve
 $$1) v(t) = v_{C1}(t) = v_R(t)+v_{C2}(t)+v_{L2}(t),$$
$$2) v(t) = v_{L1}(t) = v_R(t)+v_{C2}(t)+v_{L2}(t)$$
Right? I am trying it now, but if I am not mistaken, this is quite complex because I of the three different currents? If i try to solve 1) I find this equality? $$i_1 (t) = C1R i_3 (t) + C1L2 \frac{d^2 i_3 (t)}{dt^2} + \frac{C1}{C2} i_3 (t)$$ 


With $$i_1, i_2, i_3$$ being the current through first, second and third loop, and same for voltage $$v_1, v_2, v_3.$$

Comment: Still can't find it, I really have no idea how to solve this

Comment: Do you know about complex impedances ? That is the most efficient way of solving these, by using :
$$
L = jL\omega ; 
C=\frac{1}{jC\omega}
$$
And by swapping back in time domain. If you cannot use these, I'm working on a solution now

Comment: The first equality should give you :
$$
i_1(t)=RC1\frac{di_3(t)}{dt}+\frac{C1}{C2}i_3(t)+C1L2\frac{d²i_3(t)}{dt}
$$